# How to set a select option to change the form action

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying the make a drop down selection, change the form action, which will take the user to a different link when submitted.

Ive tried what I think should work but have not been able to, any help on what I have done wrong here would be appreciated greatly.

**js**

```
$("#time-select").change(function() {

  if (document.getElementById("time-select").value != "WEEK")
  { 
    document.getElementById("subs-form").setAttribute("action", "A");
  }

  else (document.getElementById("time-select").value != "FORTNIGHT")
  { 
    document.getElementById("subs-form").setAttribute("action", "B" );
  }

  else (document.getElementById("time-select").value != "MONTH")
  { 
    document.getElementById("subs-form").setAttribute("action", "C" );
  }

}
```

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">                              
 <form name="linkForm" id="subs-form" action="" method="GET" >

   <select id="time-select" >
    <option value="WEEK" selected>1 BAG A WEEK</option>
    <option value="FORTNIGHT">1 BAG A FORTNIGHT</option>
    <option value="MONTH">1 BAG A MONTH</option>
   </select>

    <input id="subs-submit" type="submit" value="Subscibe">

 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `!=`? and instead of `document.getElementById("time-select").value` simply use `$(this).val()`

Comment: BTW: instead of searching for the select element again, you can re-use it from the event.target: `$("#time-select").change(function( event ) { if( event.target.value == "WEEK" ) { /* … */ } });`

Comment: @feeela, How about `this.value` ???

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/sr548a14/

Comment: you missed `else if` at 2nd condition check.

Comment: @RayonDabre That depends on the event handler was set. When using `addEventListener` this is a really good option, but I don't know to which object `this` is set when using jQuery…

Comment: @feeela. The way OP has set in the question. `this` is more readable option..

Answer (score 3):

Keep your code clean as possible (using for instance jQuery selectors), see this example:

```
$("#time-select").change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val(),
      action = null;

  switch(value) {
    case "WEEK":
      action = "A"
      break;
    case "FORTNIGHT":
      action = "B"
      break;
    case "MONTH":
      action = "A"
      break;
  }

  $("#subs-form").attr("action", action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#time-select").change(function() {
    var option = document.getElementById("time-select").value;
    var el = document.getElementById("subs-form");

    switch(option) {
    case "WEEK":
      action = "A"
      break;
    case "FORTNIGHT":
      action = "B"
      break;
    case "MONTH":
      action = "C"
      break;
    }
  el.setAttribute("action", action);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[working fiddle with nicer code.](https://jsfiddle.net/tfqvtda1/1/)

```
    $("#time-select").on('change', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value !== "WEEK")
           document.getElementById("subs-form").setAttribute("action", "A");
        else if (value !== "FORTNIGHT") 
           document.getElementById("subs-form").setAttribute("action", "B" )
        else if (value !== "MONTH")
           document.getElementById("subs-form").setAttribute("action", "C" ); 
});
```